# Should I include institution holdings percentage in security analysis?

Tags: stocks

I'm trying to understand the impact of Institutional Ownership in security analysis, e.g 94% float shares of CROX are owned by institutions, https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/crox/institutional-holdings

I want to know whether the high/low ownership of a ticker would affect the buy/sell decision or the outcome of security analysis, and how it's done.

Comment: I'm not a quant, but this feels to me like something the folks in that stack might be better equipped to answer -- or have stronger opinions on, at least.

Comment: Are you asking if there some plausible model where % of institutional ownership affects a buy/sell decision?  In which case the answer is almost universally "yes".  Just about any factor affects buy/sell decisions in some plausible model.  Or are you asking whether your unspecified model should incorporate % of institutional ownership in its decisions?  In which case the answer is almost universally "depends on your model and why you're considering adding Some Additional Factor".